# How do I drop a Hive database through a Hive Action in an Oozie Workflow?

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, oozie

I have a Hive database which consists of an external table (pointing to a location in /user/hive/warehouse) and one normal table. I am using the following command to drop the database:

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS *DBNAME* CASCADE;

This command works when I run it on the hive command line, but not when I run it through a Hive .ql script called from a Hive action in an Oozie workflow.

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try executing shell script with `hive-e "drop database if exists dbname cascade;"`?

Comment: What's the error in oozie logs?

Comment: @RamananR -  I don't have access to Oozie logs :( Yarn logs didn't show any error.

Comment: Can you print the code for the Hive action, please?

Comment: Do you have access to oozie web console? (http://localhost:11000/oozie/) You can check error here also.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a script that does exactly that, save it on HDFS and then call it from Hive or HiveServer2 action?

```
 <action name="clean_temporary_tables">
    <hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
        <jdbc-url>${jdbcURL}</jdbc-url>
        <script>${hiveScript_999}</script>
        <param>TMP_TABLE=${tmp_table}</param>
    </hive2>
    <ok to="failure_email"/>
    <error to="failure_email"/>
</action>
```